# Why Window.Event is not working in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Am having two functions in the second function am using Window.event but it is not working in Firefox

I have gone through previous questions but in all those they are using only one functions but in my case am having two.Kindly do help me.

```
function ShowRemoveOptions(rowId, updateMode)
 {
 var retValue = pop('diveWBArchiveOptions');
}

function pop(controlId)
 {
    var e = window.event;
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    return false;    
}
```

Comment: because it's an internet explorer hack - p.s. the code you posted does not use events anyway, so not sure what that would even do in internet exploder

Comment: `Window.event` is IE specific.